# Panda remove duplicates but keep relationship

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

How to drop duplicates but keep the relationship.

In my case I have duplicates inside **Stock**, but no duplicates inside **Code**.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Code' : ['NSPWRUTBL1','NSPWRUTBL2','NSPWRUTBL3','NSPWRUTPK1','NSPWRUTPK2','NSPWRUTPK3'],
               'Stock' : ['890353-336','890353-336','890353-336','890353-850','890353-850','890353-850']})
print(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Actual Output :

```
         Code       Stock
0  NSPWRUTBL1  890353-336
1  NSPWRUTBL2  890353-336
2  NSPWRUTBL3  890353-336
3  NSPWRUTPK1  890353-850
4  NSPWRUTPK2  890353-850
5  NSPWRUTPK3  890353-850
```

I'm expecting to get one instance something like :

```
0  NSPWRUTBL1  890353-336
3  NSPWRUTPK1  890353-850
```

Comment: use `df.drop_duplicates('Stock')`

Comment: @coldspeed damn, I was so close :) Thank you !